# How to fix "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error with Python Requests

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to use the supportsync API (https://help.supportsync.com/crm/api/help) to extract a table of returns in my company's data.

I am able to use many of the post and get methods without a problem, but when I use the "GetReturnList" post, I am receiving the following error message: "Message":"Object reference not set to an instance of an object. at SupportSyncCRM"

This is the specific API post I am trying to use: https://help.supportsync.com/crm/api/help/Api/POST-api-app-Returns-GetReturnList

I have tried using json as opposed to data for my payload, but that does not seem to change anything.  And oddly, I have had no issue using other methods within the API.

Below is a snippet of my code:

```py
URL = 'https://[mycompany].supportsync.com/crm/api/app/Returns/GetReturnList'
headers = {'Authorization': 'Basic ' + auth.decode('ascii'), 'Content-Type':'application/json'}
payload = {'PageSize':'500', 'ReturnListType':'Receiving', 'SearchType':'0'}

r = requests.post(URL, headers=headers, data=payload)

print(r.status_code)
print(r.text)
print(r.json)

Here is the output generated by my print statements:
400
{"Message":"Object reference not set to an instance of an object. at SupportSyncCRM"}
<bound method Response.json of <Response [400]>>
```

Comment: The documentation you link to for that endpoint is really incomplete. It does suggest that you may be missing a required parameter `'ReturnListType'`, but other than that doesn't really say much (all the example strings are completely generic, so I don't have any way of guessing if your `'ReturnTypeId'` value is appropriate or not).

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out - I just tried it using a 'ReturnListType' that I know is in the data (and edited the code above), but had the same issue unfortunately.

Comment: The error is being given to you by the API, not by your code *per se*. The problem is that the code running on the server doesn't attempt to do any (or at least, enough) error detection, so when something raises an exception the exception message just gets dumped and sent back to you.

Answer (score 3):

So I reached out to their support team and they responded with this:

> Here's a sample of the POST. Make sure you have all these fields:
>
> ```
> {
>   "PageIndex":0,
>   "PageSize":50,
>   "SortColumn":"",
>   "CustomerID":"",
>   "CustomerEmail":"",
>   "ReturnListType":"",
>   "FlagGroupId":"",
>   "FlagReason":"",
>   "SearchText":"",
>   "SearchType":0,
>   "ReturnTypeId":"",
>   "CarrierMethodId":"",
>   "IsCrossShip":"",
>   "IsPrepaidReturnLabel":"",
>   "CreatedByUserId":"",
>   "ProductId":"",
>   "ReturnReasonId":"",
>   "PaymentRequired":0,
>   "CreatedDateFrom":"",
>   "CreatedDateTo":""
> }
> ```

I then altered my code to include every field in the payload and changed this line:

```
r = requests.post(URL, headers=headers, json=payload)
```

My response is now appropriately communicating with the server.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the documentation more closely, the `app` in your URL is not correct - it should not be the literal text `app`, but instead:

> {app} is the application making the request, such as: zendesk

Comment: I had initially thought something similar when I first was working with the API, but I think that if the app you are using is supportsync itself, you do use just "app" in place of {app}.

Here is an example I found on their site that just used app in their URL: https://supportsync.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360020506131-How-to-use-the-SupportSync-API